# Validate XML against XSD which imports big enum XSD

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, xsd-validation

I have an XSD which imports big XSD with more than 200k <enumeration> elements, I need to validate incoming XML against root xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http www(dot)w3(dot)org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http example(dot)com/test/test/types/2.0.0"
    xmlns:tns="http example(dot)com/test/test/types/2.0.0"
    xmlns:mun="http example(dot)com/test/test/enumXsd/types/2.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http example(dot)com/test/test/enumXsd/types/2.0"
        schemaLocation="common/enumXsd.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="test" type="tns:test"/>
    <xs:complexType name="test">
         <xs:element name="abc" type="mun:EnumEType"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

enumXsd.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:tns="http example(dot)com/test/test/enumXsd/types/2.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http example(dot)com/test/test/enumXsd/types/2.0"
    xmlns="http www w3 org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <simpleType name="EnumEType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="w1" />
            <enumeration value="2wr" />
            <enumeration value="3erwer" />
            <enumeration value="5rtete" />
             ...e.t.c...
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</schema>
```

Method getSchema() takes too long (more than 15 secs) to retrieve schema (`factory.newSchema(schemaFile);`).
Is there any ways to improve logic? Caching is not solve cause it takes a lot of memory.

```java
    private void validate(Source source) throws SAXException, IOException {
        Schema schema = getSchema();
        if (schema != null) {
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(source);
        }
    }
    public Schema getSchema() {
        String path = getSchemaPath();
        if (path == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        try (BufferedInputStream xsdStream = new BufferedInputStream(loader.getResourceAsStream(path))) {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            StreamSource schemaFile = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
            schemaFile.setSystemId(loader.getResource(path).toString());
            cachedSchema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
            return cachedSchema;
        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading schema " + path, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try profiling your code to see where the load time goes ? You can use Java Flight Recorder in order to do it (see well documented [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring)) : it may help you get what's wrong in your actual config (even if I'm pretty sure that the /real/ problem is the XSD size)

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens yes, I profilied this code, and factory.newSchema(schemaFile); is taking the most execution time (15+ secs)

Comment: Could you share you profile result ? :)

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18x_velwIv2JQQ23u98ig8Er-Rwzn-YgP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've seen your jfr file and from what I see, most of the method and memory came from parsing your XSD to get the schema info. Couldn't you cache the `Validator validator = schema.newValidator();` instance to validate your XML ? You said that caching was not an option because of memory overhead... since your actual code generate more than 24GiB memory, what is this memory overhead to keep (only) the Validator instance ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens yes it's truly genius, how I didn't think of that before. I just checked and it takes a lot less memory than caching schema. Thank you! I think that's enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments and after analysis of JFR provided, the best solution would be to cache only the `Validator` instance obtained after parsing the schema

Hope it'll solve your need.

Beware of maybe threading issue (didnt find out if Validator instance are thread-safe or not)